# Lp interpolation question

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Assume $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$. Prove that for any $p<r<q$, there exists $0<\lambda<1$ such that $$\large\|f\|_r\leq\|f\|_p^\lambda\|f\|_q^{1-\lambda}$$

---

What I tried is to first consider the case $q<\infty$. Then there exists $0<\lambda<1$ such that $$r=\lambda p+(1-\lambda)q$$

Then
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_r^r&=\int|f|^{\lambda p+(1-\lambda)q}\\
&=\|f^{\lambda p}\cdot f^{(1-\lambda)q}\|_1\\
&\leq\|f^{\lambda p}\|_{1/\lambda}\|f^{(1-\lambda)q}\|_{1/(1-\lambda)}\tag{by Holder's Inequality}\\
&=\left(\int|f|^p\right)^\lambda\left(\int|f|^q\right)^{1-\lambda}
\end{align*}

Thus $\large\|f\|_r\leq\left(\int|f|^p \right)^\frac{\lambda}{\lambda p+(1-\lambda)q}\left(\int|f|^q\right)^\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda p+(1-\lambda)q}$ which is quite similar but yet not the same as what is required.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reverse engineering:
$$
\|f\|_p^λ·\|f\|_q^{1-λ}=\||f|^λ\|_{p/λ}·\||f|^{1-λ}\|_{q/(1-λ)}
\ge\||f|^λ·|f|^{1-λ}\|_r
$$
which is valid as $p/λ>p\ge 1$, $q/(1-λ)>q\ge 1$. The third number $r$ is connected to the other exponents by
$$
\frac1r=\frac1{p/λ}+\frac1{q/(1-λ)}=\frac{λ}{p}+\frac{1-λ}{q}
$$
by Young's inequality. This allows to easily compute $ λ$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really get it though: Isn't $\||f|^\lambda\|_{\lambda p}=(\int|f|^{\lambda^2 p})^{1/(\lambda p)}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll correct this, it does not invalidate the general idea, even makes it easier.